# Why is triadic iteration 2 times slower than the recursion?

Tags: python, performance, recursion

To solve my problem, I need to put together all possible arrays of length N, containing -1, 0 and 1, and run them through some function to see whether they meet a certain criterion.

I have implemented 2 methods, a triadic numbers method and a recursion. They both return correct results, both check the same number of arrays, no red flags except that, on my machine, triadic method is almost 2 times slower. Is there any reason why this should be the case? `printIfTargetHit` is a simple numerical function, no caching or other complications that could explain the issue.

```
def triadicIteraction(signsQty):
    signs = [None for _ in range(signsQty)]
    comb = int(3**signsQty-1)
    while (comb >= 0):
        combCopy = comb
        for n in range(signsQty):
            signs[n] = 1-combCopy%3 # [0,1,2] -> [1,0,-1], correct range for signs
            combCopy = combCopy//3
        printIfTargetHit(signs)
        comb = comb - 1

def recursiveIteration(signsQty):
    def recursiveIterationInner(signs, newSign, currentOrder):
        if (currentOrder >= 0):
            signs[currentOrder] = newSign
        if currentOrder == (len(signs) - 1):
            printIfTargetHit(signs)
        else:
            recursiveIterationInner(signs,-1, currentOrder+1)
            recursiveIterationInner(signs, 0, currentOrder+1)
            recursiveIterationInner(signs, 1, currentOrder+1)
    recursiveIterationInner(signs = [None for _ in range(signsQty)], newSign = None, currentOrder = -1)
```

Full code is on github, https://github.com/Yulia5/workspace/blob/master/P2/P3/PlusesMinuses1ToN.py, I did not post all of it because I believe the example above is self-sufficient.

Performance output, timings computed as the difference between `datetime.datetime.now()`'s, first method is straightforward embedded loops.

```
Method name: <function embeddedLoopsFixed at 0x01D63D30>
Combination quantity : 16560
Combinations evaluated : 14348907
Time elapsed : 0:01:56.440000
Method name: <function recursiveIteration at 0x01D63DB0>
Combination quantity : 16560
Combinations evaluated : 14348907
Time elapsed : 0:02:20.526000
Method name: <function triadicIteraction at 0x01D63D70>
Combination quantity : 16560
Combinations evaluated : 14348907
Time elapsed : 0:04:12.297000
```

Comment: To make your `signs` list why don't you just use `range(-1, 2)`?

Comment: @CoryKramer: in what line? Do you mean 3 calls to recursiveIterationInner? I could use a for, but I decided against it, believing this will keep the code simpler.

Comment: Which profiler are you using, and what was the output?

Comment: Aside: this isn't related to the performance question, but usually when you want this output you'd use `itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat=signsQty)`.

Comment: @DSM Actually, that is related to the performance. Your suggested method would not generate a new `signs` each time and would avoid the `O(signQty)` performance penalty in each iteration.

Comment: @musically_ut: "use this other method Z" by itself doesn't provide a good answer to "why is X slower than Y", IMHO.

Comment: @DSM Was that meant as a comment on my answer below? If not, I was implicitly referring to the analysis I had provided below. Your suggestion would _also_ solve the performance problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing an `O(n)` operation each time in `triadicIteraction` here:

```
    for n in range(signsQty):
        signs[n] = 1-combCopy%3 # [0,1,2] -> [1,0,-1], correct range for signs
        combCopy = combCopy//3
```

To see this, you can use the `profile` module from the standard library and implementing the function such that each calculation happens in a separate function (named `calSigns` here):

```
def triadicIteractionGranular(signsQty):
    signs = [None for _ in range(signsQty)]
    comb = int(3**signsQty-1)

    def calSigns(combCopy):
        for n in xrange(signsQty):
            signs[n] = 1-combCopy%3 # [0,1,2] -> [1,0,-1], correct range for signs
            combCopy = combCopy//3

    while (comb >= 0):
        calSigns(comb)
        printIfTargetHit(signs)
        comb = comb - 1
```

Then:

```
>> profile.run('runCombinationCheckingMethod(triadicIteractionGranular, [], {"signsQty" : 15})')
Method name: <function triadicIteractionGranular at 0x10f466848>
Combination quantity : 16560
Combinations evaluated : 14348907
Time elapsed : 0:02:34.560533
         43394489 function calls in 154.561 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  154.561  154.561 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:119(runCombinationCheckingMethod)
   264960    0.068    0.000    0.068    0.000 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:18(onesZerosToChars)
    16560    0.355    0.000    0.488    0.000 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:27(printEqualityAsString)
 14348907   66.392    0.000   66.392    0.000 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:33(evaluate)
 14348907    8.279    0.000   75.159    0.000 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:54(printIfTargetHit)
    16561    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 <ipython-input-1-bf48bf6dbc36>:7(combinationNumber)
        1   10.580   10.580  154.560  154.560 <ipython-input-26-037769fa8fac>:1(triadicIteractionGranular)

  **** Note this line ****
  14348907   68.822    0.000   68.822    0.000 <ipython-input-26-037769fa8fac>:5(calSigns)

        1    0.000    0.000  154.561  154.561 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method now}
    16560    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    16560    0.017    0.000    0.017    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
    16561    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {range}
```

The profiles from other function looks similar, without the cost of `calSign`.

---

### Solution

There is a way of implementing the `triadicIteraction` without incurring that `O(n)` cost each time:

```
def triadicIteractionFirstPrinciple(signsQty):
    signs = [-1 for _ in range(signsQty)]
    comb = int(3**signsQty-1)

    def addOne(idx=0):
        if signs[idx] < 1:
            signs[idx] += 1
        else:
            signs[idx] = -1
            addOne(idx+1)

    while (comb >= 0):
        printIfTargetHit(signs)
        if comb > 0: addOne()
        comb = comb - 1
```

This should avoid the `O(n)` cost and give you results comparable to the other implementations.

---

On my system:

```
>> profile.run('runCombinationCheckingMethod(triadicIteractionFirstPrinciple, [], {"signsQty" : 15})')
Method name: <function triadicIteractionFirstPrinciple at 0x10f62e7d0>
Combination quantity : 16560
Combinations evaluated : 14348907
Time elapsed : 0:01:37.383544
         50568926 function calls (43394488 primitive calls) in 97.384 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I use a profiler (cProfile), the timings are very close, about 9min each. However, when I do basic timing as in code above, the timings are approximately 2min for recursion and 4min for both original and granular triadic methods. Would you be able to run the code without profiler to confirm that this result holds on your machine?

Comment: @YuliaV: you mean for both original and `FirstPrinciple` method above? Without the profiler, I remember all versions taking ~ 01:30 minutes, except `tradicIteraction` which took ~ 02:30 minutes.

Comment: @YuliaV Did you notice the comment above?

Comment: yes, tried 3 versions of triadic iteration, one is exactly as in your answer, still the same problem. I have updated the code on github; perhaps if you have the me you could run it to confirm that the issue is due to my machine.

Comment: @YuliaV I do not see the implementation of `triadicIteractionFirstPrinciple` (or a solution using `itertools.product`) in your last commit. You have implemented `triadicGranular`, but I had written that only to find the cause of the slowdown, `triadicIteractionFirstPrinciple` was the solution. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: FirstPrincpile has correct performance, thanks. I must admit I am suprised, I thought that `printIfTargetHit` would take much more time than any iteration. Thanks again!